# Cannot connect to raspberry pi via ssh - hanged

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

When I try to ssh into one of my rpis (let's call it .7) with verbose I get the following output

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.7 -v
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.7 [192.168.1.7] port 22.
```

and it just hangs endlessly.

I'm able to connect to all other raspberry pis in my house except for this particular one (no idea why). I've even tried to log into another rpi (say .62) and then I was able to ssh from it into (.7), which leads me to suspect that it's a problem with the config of my laptop, although I cannot figure out what it is.

**Update 1**

**ssh_config file**

```
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

**sshd_config file**

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

and the second file does not exist

**Update 2**

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.7 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.7 [192.168.1.7] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
```

**Update 3**

The output of tcpdump is as follows

```
sudo tcpdump  -i wlp0s20f3 -n 'port 22'
[sudo] password for myusername:            
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on wlp0s20f3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
10:11:10.086559 IP 192.168.1.5.50418 > 192.168.1.7.22: Flags [S], seq 441937362, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2181705493 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:11:11.087399 IP 192.168.1.5.50418 > 192.168.1.7.22: Flags [S], seq 441937362, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2181706494 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:11:13.103394 IP 192.168.1.5.50418 > 192.168.1.7.22: Flags [S], seq 441937362, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2181708510 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:11:17.199574 IP 192.168.1.5.50418 > 192.168.1.7.22: Flags [S], seq 441937362, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2181712606 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

where my laptop is 192.168.1.5 and my wireless card interface (obtained from ifconfig) is wlp0s20f3. I basically run the command and then in a separate terminal window tried to ssh into the (.7)

Comment: Please include the contents of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config` from your client system (Ubuntu?) [in the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/762854/edit). (The second file might not exist - that's ok, but tell us.) Also, if the files are too large you can omit all blank lines and lines starting with `#`)

Comment: @ChrisDavies added. Thanks

Comment: You've included the `sshd_config` file but I need to see the `ssh_config` file. Please check

Comment: It is kind of weird, but 2 things come to mind. One thing is log in with physical keyboard and screen and ssh to localhost, see if that works. Also increase verbosity to `-vv` or `-vvv` - when I was trying to troubleshoot connection that hung due to firewall port forwarding rules it was very helpful to see the connection being established. Another thing I did was monitoring the exchange with `tcpdump`. In that case there was only SYN connection but no SYN-ACK response. Asking tcpdump to filter out everything else helps a lot.

Comment: @r0berts I've added the output of added verbosity `-vvv` and am able to ssh localhost. Not sure what extract from tcpdump or how to use it. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: So `tcpdump` is a massively useful packet analyzer. I am a beginner with this, but in order to do any application layer communication (ssh) a lower level connection is to be established (network and transport layer i.e. `tcp/ip`). To capture packets you need to be root on raspi. Then `tcpdump  -i enp3s0 -n 'port 22` captures ssh packets (port 22). Make sure you specify correct interface the wire is connected to (pick from `ip a l` use where I put enp3s0). If you get a quick stream - problem at ssh level, if only a few packets - firewall. https://www.guru99.com/tcp-3-way-handshake.html

Comment: No expert on ssh, but `Connecting to 192.168.1.7 [192.168.1.7] port 22` seems to indicate that client is trying to connect but can not get a response. That's why tcpdump may be useful. Just noticed filter expression should be fully enclosed in singlequotes `tcpdump  -i enp3s0 -n 'port 22'` - I cut out a part  because in my case I had to say `tcpdump  -i enp3s0 -n 'port 22 and host not 192.168.1.10'` to exclude my machine from which I had sshd into the server that testing was done on. In your case not needed as you are on a physical terminal.

Comment: @r0berts I wrote above the output of tcpdump while I was trying to ssh into the raspberry pi. I think I did it right, but please let me know if not.

Comment: @Ajned you should then run a similar tcpdump on the RPi so you know if it received this traffic (and is to be the cause) or didn't (meaning an intermediate equipment such as the AP might be the cause). Also you should add the `-e` option in all cases to display the ethernet addresses (that you should feel free to obfuscate), just in case.

Comment: To my knowledge two devices on the same LAN are always connected via the router. To be clear both my laptop and the target rpi are connected to the LAN via wireless.

Comment: Never mind I didn't read correctly the tcpdump output. That's the same LAN.

Comment: just tested the tcpdump on the rpi and there are NO packets captured when I try to ssh into it from my laptop, which means that it's the router's fault?

Comment: Can you install the `socat` package and simply run `socat tcp4:192.168.1.7:22 -` : does it connect or does it also timeout? Then if it did connect, again with `socat tcp4:192.168.1.7:22,tos=16 -`

Comment: It did not connect. Same thing as it just hangs endlessly

Comment: Yet an other tool: install `iputils-arping` and run `arping 192.168.1.7` does it work? does it get the same MAC address as set on the RPi? If not the same, does using `arping` on an other RPi work, does it get the same MAC address as set on that other RPi? I admit I don't know where's the problem, it looks like it would be on the router simply because it doesn't appear to be elsewhere. Try also with ping rather than arping.

Comment: Indeed it does connect with arping and outputs the correct MAC address: `ARPING 192.168.1.7 from 192.168.1.5 wlp0s20f3
Unicast reply from 192.168.1.7 [D8:3A:DD:8A:DA:16]  75.712ms
^CSent 103 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 1 response(s)`. However with ping it does not connect `PING 192.168.1.7 (192.168.1.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 192.168.1.7 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5108ms`

Comment: You didn't tell if the MAC address was the same as on the RPi though. Anyway if tcpdump on the RPi receives the ARP requests but not the icmp requests (use `arp or icmp` as filter instead of `port 22` and use `-e`), or maybe even neither, I can only conclude the problem is on the router/switch/AP because there's no simple way to hide only half of the traffic to tcpdump on the RPi itself. Unless your router/switch/AP is actually running Unix/Linux with a CLI, there's not much more that can be done here on UL SE.

Comment: (ok you did tell it was the same MAC address). Also "Sent 103 probes (1 broadcast(s)) Received 1 response(s)" looks dubious. There should be 103 responses to 103 probes. Meaning only the broadcast got an answer (and might be the only kind of traffic received).

Comment: From within the suspicious pi this is the mac address `ip -o link show wlan0 
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether d8:3a:dd:8a:da:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for everyone's help. I'm not surprised that the root cause ended up being my crappy router (from Sky Hub). It was set up to provide a static IP address to the pi, and as soon as I changed that IP it started working again. It must have kept some misconfiguration associated with the previous IP which was cleared up when I set a new one. Thanks all.

Comment: From my brief glance up top it seems that you run tcpdump on your laptop, not rpi :-) but in this case it shows the same thing - your laptop is trying to connect to rpi (sending SYN packets to what it thinks raspi should be x.x.x.7) but getting no reply. If it worked you'd have a stream of back and forth. And you got to solution yourself - there was no such address (x.x.x.7) at the time. Well done. When I am sometimes in this uncertain situation I use nmap to quickly scan my LAN and see what exact addresses I have. So now you know - what appears 'hanged' is 'no connection'.

Comment: Hi @r0berts. Thanks, but the address was effectively 192.168.1.7 and working (I was able to connect to it via another rpi). The problem was specifically between my laptop and the rpi. There must be a bug in how the router maps static addresses, but I'm not going to spend time to understand how/why (best to get a new router). Thanks again

Comment: Maybe, however if the fault was with the hub, it did not give out the IP so the raspi did not have it. If on the other hand it had the IP (maybe from before reboot, etc) and you could connect from another rpi, then there was something with your laptop - when you connect directly to an IP address then hub/router is NOT involved at all. Either the device has a working IP and your particular laptop cannot connect (e.g. due to firewall block) or it did not get the IP so you could not connect (more likely option). Good this is resolved though, but info from here may come handy another day.